# Unable to load some projects into visual basic 2010 express

Tags: vb.net

I am facing a strange problem. Some of my projects aren´t loading into visual basic 2010 express under windows 7. But when I log with an account that has administrator privileges i am able to load those projects, build and compile without any problems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Magic crystal ball says _"Please share errors"_.

Comment: When I try to open some projects it appears "Preparing solution" and it appears to get stuck on this screen. This not happens to other projects

Comment: Make sure that the limited account has got read and write privileges to all files of the project.

Comment: Actually the projects are written inside My Documents directory, So i don´t think this is the problem...

Comment: Strange. You can try using for example [**Process Monitor**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see whether Visual Studio is actually doing anything while it appears stuck. -- Also try repairing the VS installation.

Comment: I will try Process Monitor, but i have already repaired and reinstalled the visual studio.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is to delete the hidden `.suo` file (see [**Show hidden files**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files)) located in the same folder as the solution. It holds only non-vital information such as which files were opened last time you edited the project.

Comment: I had done it already many times, now i decided to delete bin and obj folders as well and after a reboot the project seems to open again...thanks for the help Visual Vincent!

Comment: No problem. You should post that as an answer and accept it when possible. The project designer loads about 3-4 files from the `obj` folder, so the problem must've been one of those.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting .suo file and bin and obj folders, and then rebooting the IDE could load again the projects. What was strange is that another project with the same problem was working again but i did not do anything.